# Paste formatted text from rich textbox to online text editor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm creating a WinForms that scans a Word document, extracts the important data and writes it to a rich textbox with rtf format. I want to create a button that copies the rich textbox content so users can paste it in a online text editor.
The issue is that rtf can't be directly pasted into the online text editor (nothing happens when trying to paste). I tried converting the rtf to html but again, when trying to paste the clipboard nothing happens (although if I try to paste on notepad, it pastes the html text with all the tags).

How do I have to format the text in order to be able to paste it in a online text editor?

I used [this](https://github.com/mmanela/MarkupConverter) rtf to html converter

This copies only the text without format:

```
resultTB.SelectAll();
resultTB.Copy();
```

This copies the html code. If I paste it in the online editor, it pastes the text along with the tags instead of the formatted text:

```
Clipboard.SetText(RtfToHtmlConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(resultTB.Rtf));
```

This copies the rtf text. I can paste it in Word with the correct format but if I try to paste it in the oline editor nothing happens:

```
Clipboard.SetText(resultTB.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

Can't paste it anywhere. If I try to paste it in a Word, it shows the error 'Word has detected a problem':

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(new DataObject(DataFormats.Html, RtfToHtmlConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(resultTB.Rtf)), true);
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code that places the content on the clipboard

Comment: Maybe you need RTF to phpBB converter.

Comment: Clipboard.SetText(myRichTextbox.Text) ; // not myRichTextbox.Rtf

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I updated the question with the different methods I tried for copying the text.

Comment: An HTML text box can only display plain text. You need to add the markup to the page for the browser to apply the formatting.